# how to change specific error into warning in intel-fortran

Tags: ubuntu, intel-fortran

using ifort for first time.

Trying to suppress this error.

```
ifort -c -fpp -DRADM_WRF_FIM -O2 -convert big_endian -warn none   -I../../aux_src/utils/include -I/home/workhorse/WRFCHEM/WRF_CHEM_Tools/Libs/NETCDF/include  -I/home/workhorse/WRFCHEM/WRF_CHEM_Tools/Libs/grib2/include  convert_edgar_to_RELACS_REAC.f90
```

Tosses this error:

```
convert_edgar_to_RELACS_REAC.f90(17): error #6405: The same named entity from different modules and/or program units cannot be referenced.
```

I'm not familiar enough with ifort -warn to know which option will change this into a warning.

Comment: tried using -diag-disable 6405 and terminal says: Cannot disable fortran error message 6405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option, your program is simply illegal Fortran. Too illegal for such an option to disable the error to exist.

To be more specific, we would have to see the actual code. Then we could tell you which specific numbered constraint or other standard restriction is violated.